# Pandas - Normalizing JSON File searching by name

Tags: python, pandas, api, numpy, request

good day!

Could you help me, please?

With the code below, I get this output:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://openbanking.api.santander.com.br/open-banking/products-services/v1/personal-financings'
santander = requests.get(url).json()['data']['brand']['companies'][2]['personalFinancings'][4]['interestRates'][0]['applications']#['FINANCIAMENTO_MICROCREDITO']

microcredito = santander
dataframe = json_normalize(microcredito)
dataframe.head()
```

Output:

[image]

I need to get exactaly the same output, but instead of using this number 4 below, I need to find for the name of the type that belongs to 4, that is **"FINANCIAMENTO_MICROCREDITO"**. I tried to use directly the name, the type, everything and it always goes wrong. Please see the picture and code below:

```py
santander = requests.get(url).json()['data']['brand']['companies'][2]['personalFinancings']**[4]**['interestRates'][0]['applications']
```

[image]

I need to find by the name, because the name is a pattern, but number 4 isn't, and the code will be dinamic with similar data.

Could you help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure your question is clear. kindly explain further with expected output

Comment: The expected output would be exactaly the same as the first picture. If you copy and paste the code on jupyter or any IDE it will show the expected output. But in the code, I need to find the list of interestRates searching for the name "FINANCIAMENTO_MICROCREDITO", instead of the number 4 in the following piece of code ([4]['interestRates'][0]['applications']).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/) to traverse the data; within the `personalFinancings` sub data, you pass the filter `[?type=='FINANCIAMENTO_MICROCREDITO']` to get all the data within that space.

Summary of [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/): to access a key, use the `.`; to access a list, use the `[]`. The [docs](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) is quite detailed too.

```
import jmespath
import requests
import pandas as pd

 url = 'https://openbanking.api.santander.com.br/open-banking/products-services/v1/personal-financings'

santander = requests.get(url).json()

base_expression = """data
                     .brand
                     .companies[2]
                     .personalFinancings[?type=='FINANCIAMENTO_MICROCREDITO']
                     .interestRates[]
                     .applications[]"""

expression = f"""{{ interval: {base_expression}.interval, 
                    index_rate: {base_expression}.indexer.rate, 
                    customer_rate: {base_expression}.customers.rate}}"""

expression = jmespath.compile(expression)

pd.DataFrame(expression.search(santander))


  interval indexer_rate customer_rate
0  1_FAIXA       0.0279        0.1080
1  4_FAIXA       0.0399        0.0739
2  2_FAIXA       0.0000        0.0000
3  3_FAIXA       0.0359        0.8181
```

You could also just stick to plain dictionaries (`jmespath` offers convenience for nested json data)::

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)

for entry in santander['data']['brand']['companies'][2]['personalFinancings']:
    for key, value in entry.items():
         if key == "type" and value == "FINANCIAMENTO_MICROCREDITO":
             for ent in entry['interestRates']:
                 data['interval'].extend([val['interval'] 
                                          for val in (ent['applications'])])
                 data['indexer_rate'].extend([val['indexer']['rate'] 
                                             for val in (ent['applications'])])
                 data['customer_rate'].extend([val['customers']['rate'] 
                                               for val in (ent['applications'])])


pd.DataFrame(data)
  interval indexer_rate customer_rate
0  1_FAIXA       0.0279        0.1080
1  4_FAIXA       0.0399        0.0739
2  2_FAIXA       0.0000        0.0000
3  3_FAIXA       0.0359        0.8181
```